# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin ( \frac{n}{2^n})$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I was trying to determine weather or not $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin ( \frac{n}{2^n})$ converges using perhaps the D'Alembert test, but given the sine I cant really see it happening..are there other ways?

Comment: If you want to use the D'Alembert test. You should first note that $\sin(\frac{n}{2^n})\approx\frac{n}{2^n}$, since the term inside the $\sin$ tends to $0$. Calculating the limit of the ratio should be simple if you do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{n}{2^n}\right)\right|\leq \frac{n}{2^n}.$$

Comment: could  you please prove this assertion

Comment: @Bak1139: $\sin x\leq x$ for any $x\geq 0$ is really trivial.

Comment: Le $f(x)=\sin x-x$, you have that $f'(x)=\cos x-1\leq 0$ for all $x$, and thus it's a decreasing function. Moreover, $f(0)=0$, therefore $f(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$ what prove that $\sin x\leq x$ if $x\geq 0$. I let you prove that $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ for all $x$.